# Checked radio boton. ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Buenas, estoy teniendo un problema con este codigo, al abrir la opcion para editar el form, me selecciona el value 2.. Pero hay algunos que tienen value 1.. Dejo aqui el codigo para que puedan verlo..

```
function editarDestino(idDestino){
    $('#form_edi_destino')[0].reset();
    var url = 'php/destinoEditar.php';
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'id='+idDestino, // envia a PHP ej.: $_POST['id'];
        success: function(valores){
                var datos = eval(valores);
                $('#edi_destino').val('Edicion');
                $('#idDestino').val(idDestino);
                $('#strNombre').val(datos[0]);
                $('#intCiudad2').val(datos[1]);
                $('#intPais').val(datos[2]);
                $('#directorio').val(datos[3]);
                $('#directorio_portada').val(datos[14]);
                $('#archivo').val(datos[4]);
                $('#f3223f235').html("<img src=../"+datos[3]+"/"+datos[4]+" style='max-width: 50%'>" ); //portadagaleria
                $('#archivo_portada').val(datos[5]);
                $('#directorio_footer').val(datos[6]);
                $('#archivo_footer').val(datos[7]);
                $('#nombreImagen').val(datos[8]);
                $('#precio').val(datos[9]);
                $('#fecha').val(datos[10]);
                $('#estado').val(datos[11]);
                if ($('#estado').val(datos[11]) == '1'){
                $('#formEstado').find(':radio[name=estado][value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
                } else {
                    $('#formEstado').find(':radio[name=estado][value="2"]').prop('checked', true);
                }
                $('#popular').val(datos[12]);
                $('#edita-destino').modal({
                    show:true,
                    backdrop:'static'
                });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Estado</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3" id="formEstado">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="estado" value="1">
                                    Activo
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="estado" value="2">
                                    Proximamente
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Sucede que al seleccionar editar al destino, abre este modal, y tiene que mostrar si el paquete está activo o como proximamente, Activo tiene value 1, y proximamente tiene value 2.. En este caso, en la base de datos este Destino esta ACTIVO, osea marcado 1.. Y el js me esta marcando como value 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haber no se entiende mucho lo que solicitas, Tu estas diciendo que; cuando haces click en tu input con valor 2 este te abre una opción para editar un formulario?... Pero cual formulario te refieres? creo que debes extender un poco mas tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

tu error esta en la condición y en el selector podrías corregirlo así:

```
          if (datos[11]=='1'){
            $("input[name=estado][value='1']").prop("checked",true);
            } else {
                $("input[name=estado][value='2']").prop("checked",true);
            }
```

Comment: Perfectisimo, ahora si lo lee y hace checked perfectamente, solo que ahora ya no envia el value.. Jajaja!
Probé definiendo "$('#formEstado').val(datos[11]);" antes pero sigue igual que podría ser?

Comment: si quieres capturar el valor del radio lo podrias hacer asi                            var valor=$('input:radio[name= estado]:checked').val(); para enviarlo

Comment: Ya, sigue igual, pero pregunto, no es necesario poner el ID del campo?

Comment: no es necesario ,como te lo estoy diciendo es para tomar alguno de los dos valores cuando el radio este chequeado,te dejo una guía te puede servir para lo que necesitas http://www.anerbarrena.com/value-radio-button-jquery-checked-1580/

Comment: Genial te agradezco muchisimo! Una ultima cosa, creo que estoy mal ubicado.. El ultimo codigo que me habias facilitado, lo ubiqué bien, no?
$('#fecha').val(datos[10]);
      if (datos[11]=='1'){
     $("input[name=estado][value='1']").prop("checked",true);
     } else {
     $("input[name=estado][value='2']").prop("checked",true);
     }
     $('#popular').val(datos[12]);
     var valor=$('input:radio[name= estado]:checked').val();
     $('#edita-destino').modal({
      show:true,
      backdrop:'static'

Comment: si esta bien pero el código que te di ,el que captura  el valor del radio debería ir en otra función para hacer un actualizar,es lo que creo que intentas hacer,por que  lo que veo solamente estas obteniendo los datos haciendo un estilo de editar

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema esta en que siempre esta entrando en el else, porque segun lo que puedo ver en tu [html](/questions/tagged/html) no existe una etiqueta con el **id="estado"**, intenta colocarle el **id** al input:

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Estado</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3" id="formEstado">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="estado" id="estado" value="1">
                                Activo
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="estado" id="estado" value="2">
                                Proximamente
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Hola Alan, gracias por tu ayuda, el ID ya está definido debajo del label.. "<div class="col-md-3" id="formEstado">"

Comment: Hola @RodrigoRuizDiaz, me refiero al id al cual le intentas dar el valor **datos[11]** más precisamente en esta parte `if ($('#estado').val(datos[11]) == '1'){`